# C++ comparing a string to a word

Tags: c++, string, compare

I'm trying to build an program that takes a word input from user and then converts it to a number for the system to work off.

```
int FunctionName(string  WordInput) 
{
    int ReferenceNumber;

    if (WordInput.find("Specific Word"))
        {
        return ReferenceNumber = 0;
        }
    else if (WordInput.find("Specific Word 2"))
        {
        return ReferenceNumber = 1;
        }
     list goes on and has and else to get out.
```

right now the code is going into the first "if" statement and regardless of what I put as the "WordInput" it returns 0.

can ".find" not be used this way? Is there a way to do this without having to make each Specific Word as its own string?

thanks

Comment: `find` returns `npos` if the string can't be found.  It isn't a `true`, `false` function.  Please see [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Comment: Thanks for the link i'm not 100% on what they are doing. So if that wont work is there another term to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> if (WordInput.find("Specific Word"))
> ```

[`std::string::find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) returns a value of type `size_t`. It gives you the position of the search term in the string. If the search string isn't found it returns `string::npos`.

---

Instead of a long list of `if` and `else if` statements, you could use a map here. The lookup will be faster, and if you use an `std::unordered_map` it will be O(1) (constant time).

So your function can be simplified to:

```
int FunctionName(const std::string &word)
{
    //Map of string and reference number
    const static std::unordered_map<std::string, int> WordMap =
        { {"one", 1 }, { "two", 2 }, { "three", 3 } };

    auto it = WordMap.find(word);
    if (it != WordMap.end())
        return it->second;

    return 0;
}
```

Here each entry in the map is a pair of `(string, int)`. If a given word is found, the corresponding int is returned, else 0.

Working version [here](https://godbolt.org/z/hghZ8f).

Comment: awesome thanks man I'll look into this. I think this will help simplify what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```
std::string str = "Hello world, what's up today on SO?";

if (str.find("world") != std::string::npos)
    return 1;
else if (str.find("what's up") != std::string::npos)
    return 2;
else
    return 0; // or something
```

Here we've used `std::string::npos` to see if the specified word exists till the last of the string. If yes, then assigns a value for future use as you've asked to do.

Comment: Cool thanks man. This is exactly what I was trying to figure out. I need to go read up on what is happening with "!= std::string::npos" as that solved what i was having an issue with.